# Possible to use ActiveRecord methods against AR collections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to be able to pull all records from the db:

```
 u = User.all
```

And then once loaded be able to apply AR methods to the resulting collection:

```
 u.first
```

Is this possible in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you actually query the database, the results become an array instead of an ActiveRecord::Relation. (Though `#first` would still work fine, since it's a method that also exists on `Array`).

If you just need a starting point to build an ActiveRecord::Relation though, you can use `scoped`:

```
# Doesn't execute a query yet
u = User.scoped
# This now executes a query similar to SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1
u.first
```

Note that in Rails 4.0, `#all` now does the same thing as `#scoped` (whereas in Rails 3, it returns an array).

Answer (score 0):

**Why don't you try it?**

`User.all` doesn't return an AR collection it returns an Array. Get rid of the `.all` and you will have a working example.